# Hide rows based on column value using Filters

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

What I want:-

Hide rows if value of particular column is greater than specific number.

[image: Want to do this using Openpyxl]

I have searched on Google a lot and also seen several stackoverflow questions, also saw [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html) but its very very vague.

I have this code as of now.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.filters import (
    FilterColumn,
    CustomFilter,
    CustomFilters,
    DateGroupItem,
    Filters,
    )

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

data = [
    ["Fruit", "Quantity"],
    ["Kiwi", 3],
    ["Grape", 15],
    ["Apple", 3],
    ["Peach", 3],
    ["Pomegranate", 3],
    ["Pear", 3],
    ["Tangerine", 3],
    ["Blueberry", 3],
    ["Mango", 3],
    ["Watermelon", 3],
    ["Blackberry", 3],
    ["Orange", 3],
    ["Raspberry", 3],
    ["Banana", 3]
]

for r in data:
    ws.append(r)

filters = ws.auto_filter
filters.ref = "B1:B15"

flt2 = CustomFilter(operator='greaterThan', val='3')

cfs = CustomFilters(customFilter=[flt2])
col = FilterColumn(colId=1, customFilters=cfs) 
filters.filterColumn.append(col)

wb.save("filtered.xlsx")
```

But I get error

> Errors were detected in file 'D:\filtered.xlsx'Removed Feature: AutoFilter from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the whole range
So

```
filters.ref = "B1:B15"
```

should be

```
filters.ref = "A1:B15"
```

That should stop the error when opening the work book/sheet.

Also note that [Openpyxl cannot apply filters](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#using-filters-and-sorts) as this is an Excel operation.

My test opens with no error and the settings are in place.
[image]

If you need/want the filter to be applied automatically then need to use Xlwings.